# The problem is 'Error: semicolon is required' in c++

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 50

class Stack {
public:
    int top = -1;
    Location data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    bool isEmpty() { return top == -1; }
    bool isFull() { return top == MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1; }
    void push(Location& e) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            data[++top] = e;
        }
    }
    Location& pop() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return data[top--];
        }
    }
    Location& peek() {
        return data[top];
    }
};

struct Location {
    int row;
    int col;
    Location(int r,int c): row(r), col(c){}
};

int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 6;
    char map[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE] = {
        {'1','1','1','1','1','1'},
        {'e','0','1','0','0','1'},
        {'1','0','0','0','1','1'},
        {'1','0','1','0','1','1'},
        {'1','0','1','0','0','x'},
        {'1','1','1','1','1','1'},
    };

    bool isValid(int r, int c) {
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= MAX_SIZE || c >= MAX_SIZE) return false;
        else  return map[r][c] = '0' || map[r][c] = 'x';
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement maze navigation as a stack.
The isValid function says i need ';'
Marking the potential fixes ' bool isValid(int r,int c); '
They suggest me use it like this. What is the problem? Please help me TT

Comment: It is not allowed in C++ to have regular functions inside other functions. You have to use closure/lambda syntax, i.e. rewrite string `bool isValid(int r, int c) {` to `auto isValid = [&](int r, int c) -> bool {`. And add `;` at the end of such lambda function definition. I.e. full code of main() would be [like this code here](https://cutt.ly/MgjdMzp) . Then you can use isValid like a regular function e.g. `bool result = isValid(1, 2);`.

Comment: The code in the question can be reduced by at least 90% by removing the irrelevant definitions of `Stack` and `Location`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed in C++ to have regular functions inside other functions. You have to use [closure/lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function syntax.

I.e. rewrite string `bool isValid(int r, int c) {` to `auto isValid = [&](int r, int c) -> bool {`, plus add `;` at the end of such lambda function definition.

Then you can use `isValid` like regular function afterwards.

Full code of `main()` function with needed fixes down below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHBSsQwEL3nK97JttCF1IOX2IU97MGDJ0HEUkqMXQ3UtKRZWdntt9ekm@62uoIDQybzHi8zL6JpFqLi6q3vpTL44FKFEdkT2BC1ag1c@371VDzcPa@R4oYdsXeuLbvJRig/V5Z1FHCxD5IgvpBdPKGUtkU9RE/1jDKF6GWV5IfKPygud78pf47bMTKcfGtqyPaRV/LVrptd5aHzSceDXSLCYomXuq4mRsgNQo1bUBwOEGOhsUzP9g7IpBFBl2arFTa8akt20irtDSPmfkHnmbC@p7AbOZV5bxew2fTDZEZ/FbItPv0KfpkwiXEdeZ5/gDLSkb7/Bg)

```
int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 6;
    char map[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE] = {
        {'1','1','1','1','1','1'},
        {'e','0','1','0','0','1'},
        {'1','0','0','0','1','1'},
        {'1','0','1','0','1','1'},
        {'1','0','1','0','0','x'},
        {'1','1','1','1','1','1'},
    };

    auto isValid = [&](int r, int c) -> bool {
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= MAX_SIZE || c >= MAX_SIZE) return false;
        else  return map[r][c] == '0' || map[r][c] == 'x';
    };

    bool try_is_valid = isValid(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Arty's answer works, it doesn't really address your confusion. The simple answer is: C++ doesn't allow nested function definitions. So you can't define function `isValid` inside function `main`. (Arty's answer shows you how to circumvent this restriction, but I would say it is rather too advanced for what you need.)

So you have to define the `isValid` function outside `main`. `isValid` won't be called from anywhere else, so it is good practice to declare it `static` so that it doesn't clash with other functions of the same name that may be defined in different source files. (And even if you only have one source file, it's still a good habit to get into.)

`isValid` has to be defined or declared before you call it. It is a matter of taste whether to define a `static` function ahead of the calling code, like this:

```
static bool isValid(int r, int c) {
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= MAX_SIZE || c >= MAX_SIZE) return false;
    else  return map[r][c] = '0' || map[r][c] = 'x';
}

int main() {
    if (isValid(...)) etc.
}
```

or to declare if first and define it later, like this:

```
static bool isValid(int r, int c);

int main() {
    if (isValid(...)) etc.
}

static bool isValid(int r, int c) {
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= MAX_SIZE || c >= MAX_SIZE) return false;
    else  return map[r][c] = '0' || map[r][c] = 'x';
}
```

I prefer the second method myself, but many people prefer the first.

The disadvantage with this method (and the advantage with Arty's method) is that `isValid` doesn't have access to variables declared in `main`. So it can't see `MAX_SIZE` or `map`. So in this case you need to declare these variables outside the `main` function too, making them `static` for the same reason.